# Is there a useful asymptotic expansion of $(1 + z^{\sqrt{2} - 1} + z^{\sqrt{2}})^{-1}$ at $z = 0$?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I believe that an asymptotic expansion in terms of powers of $z$ can not exist because we could use the geometric series to find something of the form
$$
\frac 1{1 + z^{\sqrt 2 - 1} +z^{\sqrt 2 }} = \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom n i  z^{\sqrt 2  n -  i}
$$
so Dirichlet's Approx Thm would furnish the existence of a sequence of powers converging to $0$. Using powers of logs does not work either since they would have to be indexed from infinity to 0. What functions should one use to asymptotically analyze series whose naive expansions in terms of powers yield powers converging to $0$ (e.g. $(1+z^a+z^b)^{-1}$ where $a/b\notin \Bbb Q$)?

Comment: *...so Dirichlet's Approx Thm would...* - no no no. Both $\sqrt{2}-1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are positive (so that your "$\sqrt{2}\,n-i$" form a *discrete* set, without accumulation points). The same pertains to $(1+z^a+z^b)^{-1}$ with $a,b>0$; if $a$ and/or $b$ are negative, we multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $z^{-\min\{a,b\}}$.

Comment: What metamorphy said in different words: You cannot apply Dirichlet here, because the binomial formula constrains $i$ into the interval $0\le i\le n$. For Dirichlet to kick in you obviously need $i\approx\sqrt2 n>n$.

Comment: @metamorphy of course! I don't know why I did not see that before. Thank you!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I had been confused by this for the last couple of days because I know that a positive well ordered subset generates a well ordered semigroup, the fact that $i$ is constrained resolves my confusion.

Comment: Glad to hear that the fog has cleared!